# How to Mock Entity Framework Core Change Tracking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, entity-framework-core, moq

I have a Mocked Context Setup like this.

```
// Creates a working Fake Db Set of FakeClass Type
var fakeDbSet = Mockings.CreateDbSetMock(fakeData);  
var fakeContext = new Mock<FakeContext>();  
fakeContext.Setup(c => c.FakeData).Returns(fakeDbSet);
```

Access to the Context itself an the FakeData works as intended.
But now I'm trying to write a Unit Test for a function which accesses the ChangeTracker of fakeContext.

```
ctx.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Now the test fails and an Exception is thrown, because accessing the ChangeTracker of the mocked context returns null.

Is there a way to mock the ChangeTracker of the Context?

I already tried to setup the mocked Context with a mocked ChangeTracker, but I can't create a valid Instance, because it requieres the Context itself in the Constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the ChangeTracker call.  It gets ugly but a way to do this would be:

1. Modify your production code to setup the context via a factory so that you can use an interface for handling the context.

   ```
   using (var ctx = _data.Create())
   ```
2. Extend the interface to include a toggle for the tracker.

   ```
   void SetChangeTracking(bool enabled);
   ```
3. Extend your FakeContext to implement new wrapper interface.

Then you can call the `SetChangeTracking(true);` in your production code.  The SetChangeTracking implementation should modify the ctx object while the test code can safely return void.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases mocking EF DbContext can be very tricky, however in most cases you do not need to (and you should not also) mock the DbContext. You  can use `InMemoryDatabase` option instead of mocking the DbContext.(If you need functionalities such as `DbQuery` or any thing related to RDBMS, this will **not** help you)

```
 var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyInMemoryDB").Options;
 var ctx = new MyContext(options);
```

[Read more about Testing In Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

However if you insist on having the mocked DbContext, then take a look at this thread: https://forums.asp.net/t/2155192.aspx?Mocking+EF+Core+DBContext+with+ChangeTracker